# How to disable Ajax caching?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, caching, safari

I am having an issue with ajax caching, This was a problem in IE browser too but i fixed it by Writing the Following code.

```
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("expires","-1");
    response.setHeader("pragma","no-cache");
```

But I see Safari4.0 on MAC is Caching the Ajax request(We have a requirment to support this). Fire Fox never a problem. Regarding this "Expire" i am setting it to -1, i see lot of places it is set 0 or some old date from past. Will it make a difference?

Answer (score 13):

Send an extra parameter with your GET request that will never be the same, for example, the current timestamp. Something like:

```
url = url + '&nocache=' + new Date().getTime();
```

This will prevent caching.

Comment: While this will work, it is a hack -- I'd like to know why Safari is apparently ignoring headers and inappropriately caching things.

Comment: @josh3736: I don't know. Could be part of the fact that the variable is `response` and the headers should probably be set on `request` using `setRequestHeader`. But this is the "industry-standard" way to prevent caching, it's much less of a hack than setting headers :)

Comment: @ minitech We are setting the new date().getTime();. We are using our own ajax library in that i see we are doing it.          this.get = function(queryString) { m_requestId = new Date().getTime(); m_request.open("GET", queryString, true); m_request.send(null); return m_requestId; };

Comment: @minitech I would hardly say setting headers is a hack. Setting a header is the appropriate way to handle the cache - the date trick is used because of IEs aggressive ajax caching.

Comment: I assumed the `response.setHeader` calls were *server* code, where we would be setting response headers.  Regarding headers vs. cache-busting parameter, you're actually backwards: HTTP headers are the proper, RFC-specified place to control client and proxy caching.  Cache-busting querystring parameters are just a commonly-used hack that rely on side effects rather than standards.

Answer (score 3):

First, a note on your `Expires` header.  Your question doesn't specify what server framework you're using, so I'm not sure if this is applicable.  However, it looks like you might be sending an invalid `Expires` header.

The [RFC requires `Expires` to be a date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21), however you appear to be setting the header to a literal `"-1"`.  There are many frameworks that have an expires property on their HTTP response object that takes an int and automatically calculates a date that is that number of seconds from now.

Use a [HTTP inspector](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to ensure that your server is sending a validly formatted date and not `-1` in the `Expires` header.

---

You might try making your `Cache-Control` header more restrictive:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

`must-revalidate` tells caches that they must obey any freshness information you give them.  HTTP allows caches to serve stale representations under special conditions; by specifying this header, you’re telling the cache that you want it to strictly follow your rules. <sup>[[1]](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) section 9.5 about POST

```
   Responses to this method are not cacheable, unless the response
   includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields. However,
   the 303 (See Other) response can be used to direct the user agent to
   retrieve a cacheable resource.
```

So, the browser **must not** cache POST responses, unless the response specifies otherwise. In the same time, browsers **may** cache GET responses, unless the response specifies otherwise. So, for the requests that **should not** be cached, such as AJAX requests, POST is preferrable method.

If you, for any reason, don't want to use POSTs for AJAX, you should use the *trick* mentioned by *minitech*, it is in fact widely used to force browser to load current version of any resource.