# Clear Web App Local Storage on IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I'm a web app developer trying to test my app, but Apple has changed the way they save web app data when you add it to the home screen.

How can I clear my web app's local storage so I can see updates to my code?

Comment: in Mobile Safari, right? or in a native app that's using UIWebViews?

Answer (score 0):

iOS Apps are stored in a sandbox. So every application has its own directory and working space.

In that working space all data of the application gets stored. This includes documents, library files, temporary files, the application bundle, as well as the preferences file.

When a user chooses to delete an app, the whole sandbox gets removed, including those preferences.

*Here are some Solutions for Handling App sandbox data*

**Deleting all the files in the iPhone sandbox**

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *directoryContents = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    for (NSString *path in directoryContents) {
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        BOOL removeSuccess = [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
        if (!removeSuccess) {
            // Error handling
            ...
        }
    }
} else {
    // Error handling
    ...
}
```

[**Clear Safari Cache**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754305/why-my-mobile-safari-cache-wont-clear)

**Clear UIWebView Cache**

```
// Flush all cached data
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793278/deleting-all-the-files-in-the-iphone-sandbox-documents-folder)

Hope this helps!